# CSS hover does not affect on other element

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS `:hover` works when I use it for it's own element, but when i tried to affect  another element, it had no effect.

For example, when I hover this button, the hidden links should appear, but they do not.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
}
.dropbutton {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  background: #017678;
  border: none;
}
.dropcontent a {
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #9fa0a8;
  display: none;
}
a:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}
.dropbutton:hover .dropcontent {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbutton">SHOW CONTENT</button>
  <div class="dropcontent">
    <a href="#">c1</a>
    <a href="#">c2</a>
    <a href="#">c3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A space is a [descendant combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators). It targets descendants, but the div is not a descendant of the button, it is a sibling.

You need to use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators) instead: a plus sign.

You also need to target the links (which are descendants of `.dropcontent` so you should use a descendant combinator there) since it is those which you have set `display: none` on and not the div.

```
.dropbutton:hover + .dropcontent a {
```

Comment: Beat me to it. You were quick :)

Comment: Beware that you may not tamper with the structure afterwards or this would break.

Answer (score -1):

I'd move the `display: none;` to the `.dropcontent` itself - as it now pertains to its anchors, that is, links, and as such, neither current answer would work -, then use

```
.dropbutton:hover + .dropcontent
{
    display: block;
}
```

But you must not add anything between dropbutton and dropcontent afterwards, or it will not work any more.

Comment: Please add comment as why did you downvote if you do.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Javascript to do this?

```
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('.dropbutton')[0],
    menuContent = docuemnt.getElementsByClassName('.dropcontent')[0];

button.onmouseover = function(event) {
    menuContent.style.display['block'];
}
button.onmouseout = function(event) {
    menuContent.style.display['none'];
}
```

With a slight change to your CSS: `.dropbutton` should have `display: none`, and you should remove the `display: none` from `.dropcontent a`